# jquery toggle effect resetting element width

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

For some reason when i use the jquery toggle function with a speed option, the element width is animated at the same time (from 50% of the width to its full extent). I don't recall noticing it in previous version of jquery. Is there a way to make sure the toggle doesn't touch the width? The problem is that i have some floated content in the element, so when toggled , the floated layout is broken until the animation is completed.
Any ideas on how to fix this?

i am using the latest version of jquery : 1.3.2.

Comment: can you post your example code to a public URL using http://www.jsbin.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to toggle along the vertical axis, take a look at the [slideToggle](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/slideToggle#speedcallback) function.